# gethostbyname fail after switching internet connections

Tags: macos, mpi, osx-yosemite

I often (but not always) get the following error when running MPI jobs after switching wifi hosts.

```
Fatal error in MPI_Init: Other MPI error, error stack:
MPIR_Init_thread(498)..............: 
MPID_Init(187).....................: channel initialization failed
MPIDI_CH3_Init(89).................: 
MPID_nem_init(320).................: 
MPID_nem_tcp_init(171).............: 
MPID_nem_tcp_get_business_card(418): 
MPID_nem_tcp_init(377).............: gethostbyname failed, MacBook-Pro.local     (errno 1)
```

Everything works fine in the coffee shop, and then when I come home, I get the above error.  Nothing else has changed.

I've checked the /etc/hosts and /private/etc/hosts files, and they look okay -

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
```

I can ping localhost, so the problem isn't exactly that localhost isn't resolved.

Rebooting always fixes the problem, but is there something simple I can do to "reset" my system so that it recognizes local host?

I don't have access to the details of the MPI initialization routines in the code I am running and am not making any explicit calls to gethostname.

I am using MPICH 3.1.4 (built Feb, 2015) and am running OSX 10.10.3

Comment: are you looking up localhost, or are you looking up macbook-pro.local?  is MPICH running a local daemon?  if so have you tried restarting the daemon (perhaps it has old DNS server ip cached, or the like)

Comment: Thanks!   How do I restart the local daemon?  As for localhost, I did : `ping localhost`, and got a response.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is very simple - here is what seems to work.

I edited the file `/etc/hosts` (or `/private/etc/hosts`, in OSX) and added the line

```
127.0.0.1   macbook-pro.local
```

so now my hosts files looks like :

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
127.0.0.1   macbook-pro.local
```

Comment: I just ran into this issue on a new laptop, and so used the fix I originally posted above.   It worked, so would consider this the right way to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

We were facing this issue intermittently on our CI server. It seems that setting the environment variable `MPICH_INTERFACE_HOSTNAME` to `localhost` helped.